# simplify the python code with while loop and if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am totally new for python3. I need to write some easy process as following. But wondering if there is anyway I can simplify the following code?

```
def dosomething ( i ):
    print(i);

n = 12
i = 1
while n > 0:
    if i == 6:
        i = 5
    dosomething( i )
    i += 1
    n -= 1
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with this example or if your constants are significant, but here's one approach that creates the same output a bit more simply:

```
def dosomething ( i ):
    print(i);

n = 12
i = 1

for j in range(1, 6):
    dosomething(j)

for k in range(n - 5):
    dosomething(5)
```

In general, if the number of iterations is known in advance, you should express it with a for loop rather than a while loop.

Comment: i would like i to count from 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,9,10,...etc

Comment: Okay. The significance of the other values in your code is still unclear, but if you merely want `i` to take on those values in a loop, a `for` loop is what you would want. In this case, `for i in range(n): dosomething(i)` is closest to what you're describing right now. Does that help?

Comment: yes, thank you. it turns out i use for `n in range(12):` and put if else condition to pass i into dosomething function.

Comment: if there is any shorthand for if elfi condition like i should be 5 if i between 5 to 8. i should be 4 if i equal 9?

Comment: Not particularly. That's exactly what those conditional statements are made for.

Answer (score 0):

this would work, simplifying the while loop into a for loop:

```
i = 1
for n in range(1, 13):
    if i == 6:
        i = 5
    dosomething(i)
    i += 1
```

if you are trying to avoid dosomething(6):

```
for n in range(1, 13):
    if n != 6:
        dosomething(n)
```